# MySQL-Query with IN, is this result possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT      ntc.newsID, ntc.categoryID, category.title
FROM        news_to_category ntc
LEFT JOIN   news_category category
ON          ntc.categoryID = category.categoryID
WHERE       ntc.newsID IN (2,4)
```

on this table

```
news_to_category
    categoryID newsID
    32         2
    33         2
    23         4

news_category
    categoryID title
    32         Important
    33         Cars
    23         Fishing
```

Result should be:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 32
                    [1] => Important
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 33
                    [1] => Cars
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                    [1] => Fishing
                )
        )
)
```

The key of the second array should be the newsID. Is this result possible with just 1 query?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can manipulate result array with php

Comment: Yeah I know but how will that work? I dont think the sql query is correct like that..

Comment: Post the expected result and the result which you are getting. You can manipulate the arrangement in php.

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct but will return an one dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

Works like this(table names are little different):

```
 SELECT     ctn.newsID, ctn.categoryID, cat.title
    FROM        wcf".WCF_N."_cnews_news_to_category ctn
    LEFT JOIN   wcf".WCF_N."_cnews_category cat
    ON          ctn.categoryID = cat.categoryID
    WHERE       newsID IN (".implode(',',$newsIDs).")

    $result = WCF::getDB()->sendQuery($sql);
    $news = array();        
    // save info
    while ($row = WCF::getDB()->fetchArray($result)) {
        $news[$row['newsID']][] = $row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php

```
<?php

while($res=mysql_fectch_assoc($resource))
{
$result[$res['newsID']][]=array($res['categoryID '],$res['title']);

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT      ntc.newsID, ntc.categoryID, category.title
                    FROM        news_to_category ntc
                    LEFT JOIN   news_category category
                    ON          ntc.categoryID = category.categoryID
                    WHERE       ntc.newsID IN (2,4)");

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    if(!isset($array[$row["newsID"]]))
    $array[$row["newsID"]]=array();

    array_push($array[$row["newsID"]], array($row["categoryID"],$row["title"]));
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
```